# get last value before '/'

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

const filePath = window.top.$('#FilePath').val();
 const snipEnd = str => str.endsWith('/') ? str.slice(0, -2) :

alert(filePath);

//add snipEnd somewhere
    console.log( "ready!" );
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="FilePath" id="FilePath" value="/content/enforced/6e83-YO_SB_Deb/">
```

Hi,
I am trying to get the last value found before the last '/'. Somehow alert the "6e83-YO_SB_Deb/"

Comment: `"/content/enforced/6e83-YO_SB_Deb/".split("/").slice(-2,-1).join('')` is one way

Comment: split is not a function.. this gives an error

Comment: well, what is `str` in your code? Personally, I was talking about getting the value from the `filePath` variable  - still in your code, `str` must also be a string, since `startsWith` works for you

Comment: ok i got it work! thanks

Comment: `.match(/[^/]+(?=\/$)/)[0]` is another method

Comment: @Bravo why did you not ad an answer?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen because "split is not a function" error, so, obviously the code isn't the code OP is having trouble with.

Comment: @JoelPeltonen - you convinced me :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways I can think of off the top of my head

I've called the results `methodOne` and `methodTwo` in the code below

```js
const filePath = '/content/enforced/6e83-YO_SB_Deb/';
const methodOne = filePath.split('/').slice(-2)[0];
const methodTwo = filePath.match(/[^/]+(?=\/$)/)[0];

console.log(methodOne);
console.log(methodTwo);
```